# How do I detect when a package gets installed, removed, or updated under Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, daemon, dpkg

I am looking for a way to know that the list of packages installed on an Ubuntu system changed while my C++ application is running.

I have a daemon which is expected to tell other applications whenever certain things change on the system, one of them is a list of installed packages. I want to track a certain number of packages such as Apache2, Cassandra, NTP, Postfix... to be able to tell what is running and what is not running on each computer in a cluster. This should be continuous so the status remains up to date (at least within a minute or two.) However, reading the list of installed packages with something such as `dpkg -l ntp` is very long and uses quite a bit of processing time, so I would like to run that command only when a change to the installation is made (which should be a relatively rare event, assuming we have security updates at most once a day, I should not have to run `dpkg -l ...` more than once a day, unless the administrator adds/removes items during the day, I need to detect those changes quickly enough.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a script to track changes via the `--pre-invoke` and `--post-invoke` hook options. Those should run before and after the dpkg lock has been acquired so should be safe to run `dpkg-query` commands from there.

Please check the `dpkg` man page for more details.

Comment: On the command line, it would not work as the person running `dpkg` would have to be pro-active and make sure to add my hooks... Not likely to happen. But that made me think they have a way to install hooks under `/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/`. So that is the way to do it!

Comment: Right, sorry I thought it was obvious from the reply, but I guess not, as the option in -- form might have been more confusing than otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `apt-get` or `apt`, the place to look at is the `apt`'s history logs, precisely check the files

```
/var/log/apt/history.log*
```

On the other hand, `dpkg` tracks all the installed/removed packages, in the files:

```
/var/log/dpkg.log*
```

Snippets from my system:

```
Start-Date: 2015-08-04  19:55:15
Commandline: apt-get install youtube-dl
Install: libavresample1:amd64 (9.11-2ubuntu2, automatic), libavfilter3:amd64 (9.11-2ubuntu2, automatic), libquvi7:amd64 (0.4.1-1ubuntu3, automatic), libbs2b0:amd64 (3.1.0+dfsg-2ubuntu2, automatic), libav-tools:amd64 (9.11-2ubuntu2, automatic), libquvi-scripts:amd64 (0.4.21-1, automatic), youtube-dl:amd64 (2014.02.17-1), libmpg123-0:amd64 (1.16.0-1ubuntu1, automatic), libavdevice53:amd64 (9.11-2ubuntu2, automatic), mplayer2:amd64 (2.0-701-gd4c5b7f-2ubuntu2, automatic), libvdpau1:amd64 (0.7-1, automatic), rtmpdump:amd64 (2.4+20121230.gitdf6c518-1, automatic)
End-Date: 2015-08-04  19:55:36

Start-Date: 2015-08-18  14:41:02
Commandline: apt-get install sshpass
Install: sshpass:amd64 (1.05-1)
End-Date: 2015-08-18  14:41:03
```

Comment: Would that work whichever way I install a package? (i.e. aptitude or even directly dpkg?)

Comment: @AlexisWilke Just `apt`'s log

Comment: Apt runs `dpkg` under the hood so monitoring the `dpkg` logs should be sufficient.